# Many to Many mapping without join table

Tags: sql, database, orm, relational-database

I have a question about mapping tables, I have read a lot of references talk that it's hard to do many to many mapping without join table.

But what if table A have a foreign key from table B and vice verse, for example STUDENT table has a foreign key from CLASS table that represents the class of each student "class to student one to many", and CLASS  table has a foreign key from STUDENT table that represents the students that belong "student to class one to many"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you give would not work if you have a properly normalized database. Just consider the following concept:

In your student table, you *should* have a primary key that defines each individual student. This means there is only going to be one row for each. You will have a column that represents the class, but again, if you are following proper design techniques that column should only contain one value. This means, that you can only have one row for each student, and that they can only be assigned one class. The same would apply for class, you should only have one row, and even if you gave it a student column, it would only be able to reference one student.

Of course, you could have a poor design that allows for multiple rows of students, but it would open up for countless anomalies and would be terrible to maintain moving forward. I *strongly* recommend against that.

What I recommend you do is create an intersection table that uses a composite key of course and student references. Your design could look something like this:

```
student:
| student_id | name | phone |

course:
| course_id | description | location |

enrollment:
| course_id | student_id |
```

**EDIT**

What you mentioned in the comments will not work if you followed the above instructions. Consider this student table that does not allow more than one row for student:

```
| student_name | class   |
+--------------+---------+
|    John      | Science |
|    Adam      | Math    |
|    Jane      | Science |
```

Now, nothing would stop me from creating a class table like this:

```
| class   | student_name |
+---------+--------------+
| Science |    Joe       |
| Math    |    Jane      |
```

Yes, all the information is there. I know that Adam is in Math, John is in Science, Joe is in Science, and Jane is in both Math and Science.

But now, what happens if Adam wants to take science also? He can't, because there is already a row for `Science` and a row for `Adam`. If you change either one, you lose a piece of information.

Comment: I could have multiple class for one student by using the same student_FK on multiple row in class table, and I could have multiple student for one class by using the same class_FK on   multiple row in student  table.

Comment: While it may work to an extent, you will find shortcomings very quickly. Please see my edit, @user3305603.

Answer (score 2):

When your `STUDENT` table has a foreign key to the `CLASS` table, it means that each student row can correspond to at most one class row. This, in turn, means that when a student takes more than one class, you must enter multiple rows for the same student.

Likewise, when your `CLASS` table has a foreign key to the `STUDENT` table, your model assumes that a single class can be taken by at most one student, or be represented by multiple rows in the `CLASS` table.

When you have multiple rows for the same item, your data is *denormalized*. This is generally a bad thing. Although there are a few situations when you cannot avoid it without hurting performance too much, this is definitely not one of them.

That is why you want a table "in between" your students and your classes.